# Launching an activity of the application on clicking the notification

Tags: android

I like to launch one of my activities in my application on clicking the notification.
I designed a pending intent as discussed in the link [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).
But when i click the notification, an activity is launched but that is not the activity supposed to launch from my application. Just the activity that has same class name as my activity is launched. I set a break point in my activity and the break point is never hit.
What is wrong? NotificationListActivity is the one I like to launch. Now the activity titled with NotificationListActivity is launched, but not my activity.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(thisclasscontext, NotificationListActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("MOBILENUMBER", tel);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(thisclasscontext);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationListActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: you want to launch NotificationListActivity when notification is clicked? Your MainActiivty is launched and say you have a button and when you click motification appears and when you click the notification you need to navigate to NotificationListActivity? I am confused

Comment: can you post your logcat? Why would you have two activities with the same name.

Comment: @Raghunandan when I got sms with a designated info from a designated number, then my application raises a notification. When the user clicks the notification I like to launch one of the activities in my application

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below as a reference it works

```
  public void notification()
  {
      int mId=1;
      NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(SecondActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
  }
```

Comment: this code is implemented in the BroadcastReceiver class.  So MainActivity.this can't be used

Comment: you can pass the activity context to the constructor of BroadCastReceiver class