# Launching an activity from notification

Tags: android

I am trying to launch an activity from the notification.
I have activity A. The activity A is launched from clicking on the notification. Once the activity A is launched, I like to get back to MainActivity upon pressing the phone's back button. To happen like that I implement as follow. The code is implemented in the BroadcastReceiver. I am having the compilation error at this line `Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, theClass);` Because MainActivity.this is not valid in the BroadcastReceiver class. How can I make it correct?

```
Class theClass = Class.forName("sg.SanThit.TrackMe.NotificationListActivity");
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, theClass);
resultIntent.putExtra("MOBILENUMBER", tel);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this);
 // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(theClass);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                               0,
                               PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                           );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: ??? Why not just override the keypress and launch `MainActivity` when back is pressed?

Comment: I am not clear. How to do that?

Comment: Hmm.. first, let me confirm if I have understood you correctly. Do you want to launch `MainActivity` when user presses back key while in activity A?

Comment: He wants to go form Activity A to the Activity MAIN, but main activity does not exist on the stack as a previous activity because Activity A is created directly from the notification.

Comment: Yeah clicking on the notification, A is launched. When user presses back key, go back to MianActivity while in A.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching an activity of the application on clicking the notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622654/launching-an-activity-of-the-application-on-clicking-the-notification)

Comment: @Ragh This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Dusan i only said possible duplicate

Comment: This is a very fair question... the one who VOTED DOWN probably does not have an answer... stupid man, if you ask me